# numpy.polyfit gives empty residuals array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, curve-fitting

I use numpy.polyfit to fit a 2nd order polynom to a set of data

`fit1, fit_err1, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(xint[:index_max],
                                      yint[:index_max],
                                      2,
                                      full=True)`

For some few examples of my data, the variable `fit_err1` is empty although the fit was successful, i.e. `fit1` is not empty!

Does anybody know what an empty residual means in this context? Thank you!

EDIT:
one example data set:

```
x = [-488., -478., -473.]
y = [ 0.02080881,  0.03233648,  0.03584448]

fit1, fit_err1, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(x, y, 2, full=True)
```

result:

```
fit1 = [ -3.00778818e-05  -2.79024663e-02  -6.43272769e+00]
fit_err1 = []
```

I know that fitting a 2nd order polynom to a set of three point is not very useful, but then i still expect the function to either raise a warning, or (as it actually determined a fit) return the actual residuals, or both (like "here are the residuals, but your conditions are poor!").

Comment: Can you give a small example of some data that causes this behavior?

Comment: A second order polynomial can be fit to three points exactly, so the residuals would all be zero. If the only situation in which you get no residuals is when the number of points is exactly one more than the order of the polynomial, that's your explanation of what's going on.

Comment: @Jaime: good point! But in case the fit is exact, I'd expect the residuals to be rather 0 than [], isn't it?

Comment: You may want to open this as a bug/feature request on [numpy's github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues).

Comment: If the exact fit is the root cause for this strange behaviour, then you are right! I will send a mail to the numpy team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jaime, if you have three points a second order polynomial will fit it exactly. And your point that the error should be rather `0` than an empty array makes sense, but this is the current behavior of `np.linalg.lstsq`, [which is where `np.polyfit` is wrapped around](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L1377).

We can test this behavior doing the least-squares fit of a `y = a*x**0 + b*x**1 + c*x**2` equation that we know the answer should be `a=0, b=0, c=1`:

```
np.linalg.lstsq([[1, 1 ,1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 9]], [1, 4, 9])
#(array([ -3.43396424e-15,   3.88578059e-15,   1.00000000e+00]),
# array([], dtype=float64),
# 3,
# array([ 10.64956309,   1.2507034 ,   0.15015641]))
```

where we can see that the second output is an empty array. And [this is intended to work like this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1763).

Comment: Thank You @Saullo Castro! I still don't get the intention behind the empty return value, but at least now i know it is empty by Intention, i.e. not a bug but a feature!

Comment: @jkalden remember that `NumPy` is constantly evolving and you are welcome to contribute discussing this topic in the mail list (numpy-discussion@scipy.org)

Comment: So the takeaway is that in the current implimentation an empty array means it fit exactly?